# Unexpected token on JSX code npm build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, babeljs

I realize this has been asked before, but I have tried the answers to them and they haven't worked out.

I started learning react and I am having trouble with building my app. I looked long and hard into the dependencies but they look alright to a beginner like me. I have put the react code in a separate file, main.js, and it should render something into a index.html component.

npm error says:

```
Unexpected token (24:12)
|     renderNormal() {
|         return (
|             <div className="container">
|                 <div className="content">{this.props.children}</div>
|                 <button onClick={this.edit} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
```

Here is my packages.json dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"webpack": "^3.6.0"
},
```

And lastly, here is my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "env"],
  "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx", "react-html-attrs"]
}
```

Using `npm 3.10.10`

Comment: Might need to name your file `main.jsx`. Otherwise you should specify how you're building from JSX & ES6/7 to ES5 or whatever's needed for the browser. Things like your webpack config and how you use webpack etc.

Comment: Tried that, still same problem

Comment: What is your webpack config?

Comment: What do you mean?